# How do I retrieve the time value from the Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table `shows` with a time column called `start_time`.  In the view, when I do:

```
<%= show.start_time %>
```

I get

```
2000-01-01 21:00:00 UTC
```

The `21:00` is stored properly in the database as time only.  How can I display the time only in the view minus the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be

```
show.start_time.to_s(:time)
```

or using any of the options listed at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime you can do stuff like:

```
show.start_time.to_s("%H:%M %P")
```